# How to make the correct SQL for authorization scheme in Oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to ask how to create authorization scheme for admin only. I just wrote this SQL, but it does not work for admin email:

```
SELECT EMAIL 
FROM USERS 
WHERE lower(EMAIL) = lower(V('APP_USER')) 
  AND lower(EMAIL) LIKE '%admin%';
```

Can anyone guide me how to create the correct SQL statement?

Comment: you should first test with `select v('APP_USER') from dual` how the name from the admin is, and if it has admin in it

Comment: What happens when you have a user named `Badminton`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement; and the expected output for the sample data. At the moment, you have not described what an "admin email" looks like nor what a "correct" SQL statement behaves like so the only way to answer the question is to guess what you are expecting. Please help us to help you and provide a complete explanation of the problem.

Comment: Please be more clear. An authorization scheme is for users to log in. What is your authorization scheme supposed to do - only allow users that have the string "admin" in their email ? What about other users that try to log in ?
Please provide your complete function code. What does "does not work" mean ?